# Apache airflow with conditional statements

Tags: bash, postgresql, jar, conditional-statements, airflow

I am new to Airflow. I want to do an operation like below using airflow operators.

Briefly I want to read some data from a database table and according to the values of a column in that table I want to do different tasks.

This is the table which I used to get data.

```
+-----------+--------+
| task_name | status |
+-----------+--------+
| a         |      1 |
| b         |      2 |
| c         |      4 |
| d         |      3 |
| e         |      4 |
+-----------+--------+
```

From the above table I want to select the rows where status=4 and according to their task name run the relevant jar file (for running jar files I am planning to use Bash Operator). I want to execute this task using Airflow. Note that I am using PostgreSQL.

This is the code which I have implemented so far.

```
from airflow.models import DAG
from airflow.operators.postgres_operator import PostgresOperator
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from airflow import settings

#set the default attributes
default_args = {
    'owner': 'Airflow',
    'start_date': datetime(2020,10,4)
}

status_four_dag = DAG(
    dag_id = 'status_check',
    default_args = default_args,
    schedule_interval = timedelta(seconds=5)
)

test=PostgresOperator(
    task_id='check_status',
    sql='''select * from table1 where status=4;''',
    postgres_conn_id='test',
    database='status',
    dag=status_four_dag,
)
```

I am stuck in the place where I want to check the task_name and call the relevant BashOperators.

Your support is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[XComs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/concepts.html?highlight=xcom#xcoms) are used for communicating messages between tasks. Send the JAR filename and other arguments for forming the command to `xcom` and consume it in the subsequent tasks.

For example,

```
check_status >> handle_status
```

`check_status` - checks status from DB and write JAR filename and arguments to `xcom`

`handle_status` - pulls the JAR filename and arguments from `xcom`, forms the command and execute it

Sample code:

```py
def check_status(**kwargs):
    if randint(1, 100) % 2 == 0:
        kwargs["ti"].xcom_push("jar_filename", "even.jar")
    else:
        kwargs["ti"].xcom_push("jar_filename", "odd.jar")


with DAG(dag_id='new_example', default_args=default_args) as dag:
    t0 = PythonOperator(
        task_id="check_status",
        provide_context=True,
        python_callable=check_status
    )

    t1 = BashOperator(
        task_id="handle_status",
        bash_command="""
            jar_filename={{ ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='check_status', key='jar_filename') }}
            echo "java -jar ${jar_filename}"
        """
    )

    t0 >> t1
```